# code unable to reach else statement in elif in python

Tags: python-2.7

Else condition is not executing .I am unable to print data after else statement.
I am getting output aS resp=[] instead of resp[0]=-1

why i am getting this ?is there any mistake in my code::

consider the following code snippet

```
 import os
 import re
 import time
 import sys
 import random
 res="Received CommandCEPTfrfg45g45g54g54hg \
 Received ComTvtv56g56gh65ghbtg56hg3g5ty7u6y45g4 vReceived ComRCE_vrff \
   Rece mcmprepmoinReceivedCommanAPcdcdcdcReceived CommanP"
 def checkit(val):
     resp=[]
     test_comment=[]
     if val=='0x01':
         print "reached condition"
         if re.search("Received Command fcvdfc:",res):
            resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x02'):
     #if re.search("Received",res):
        resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x03'):
         if re.search("Received Command wedwedewd:",res):
            resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x04'):
         if re.search("Receive 1",res):
            resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x05'):
         if re.search("Receiv2",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x06'):
         if re.search("Recei2",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x07'):
         if re.search("Received2 Co",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x08'):
         if re.search("Receiv3",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x09'):
         if re.search("Received7",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x0a'):
         print "reached condition"
         if re.search("Received8",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x0b'):
         print "reached condition"
         if re.search("Received8",res):
             resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x0c'):
          print "reached condition"
          if re.search("ReceivedT9",res):
              resp.append(0)
     elif(val=='0x0d'):
         print "reached condition"
         if re.search("fwefef",res):
            resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
         #return
     test_comment.append(str(res))
     resp.append(test_comment)
     #print test_comment
     return resp

li=['0x01','0x02','0x03','0x04','0x05','0x06','0x07','0x08','0x09','0x0a','0x0b','0x0c','0x0d'];
for i in range(10):
    val=random.choice(li)
    print val
    ret=checkit(val);
    print "response:",ret,"\n"
```

Comment: When would it ever get called with a `val` it isn't checking for?

Comment: you can use `switch` instead of `if..elif`

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh in Python? Might want to double-check that...

Comment: is  far as i known switch case is not there in python

Comment: this code works fine with me.... for me it executes the else statement perfectly. what i did is changed all the values in the li list so random.choice selects any one of these changed values and then forces the execution to perform else condition. In response the execution does go to else condition and does perform the tasks enlisted in else condition. here is the code, you can cross verify [link](http://rextester.com/AMVH87738)

Comment: Thanks  for your answer,i got the answer but i have still one doubt what the difference '0x02' and '0x020' or '0x2' makes.

Comment: @chandra *leading* zeroes don't matter, but *trailing* ones do; `0x002 == 0x2 == 2` but `0x20 == 32`.

Comment: yes.I got that point but when i use '0x02' my else case is not executing if i use '0x2'.it is working

Comment: Ah; because you're comparing to a **string**, not a number - it would be better to use e.g. `int(val, 16) == 0x02` (note conversion to integer and absence of quotes).

Comment: Even though i use int(val,16)==0x02 i am unable to get the Correct result. Suppose i have valid true statement in the string"res" and some false conditions.It should produce the Result with True conditions resp[o] and false conditions resp[-1].But i am not getting the required output what i want.

Comment: @chandra I don't see why your 'else' part should be executed. Your list 'li' contains all the valid scenarios which are there in the function 'checkit'. Calling 'random.choice(li)' will obviously give you the valid values from that list only.That's why all 'if' conditions are getting executed i.e. conditions like these `if val=='0x01':`.The answer which you have given is getting into the new 'else' condition which you have written within those RE check of 'if'. The RE check is failing and going into it's 'else' part and not into the outer 'else' block which you have removed in your 2nd progam.

Comment: Just for the records, why you need semicolons(;) in your program. Python doesn't care about those.It's present at 2 places

Answer (score 0):

```
checkit("0x00")    # makes the else branch executed
```

Comment: checkit(0) will execute only else block but i need the code that should run for both True and False conditions.

Comment: What about adding '0x00' to your `li` list?

Answer (score 0):

It is working if i place else condition after if condition but not at last i don't know why?

```
import os
import re
import time
import sys
import random
res="Received CommandCEPTfrfg45g45g54g54hg \
Received ComTvtv56g56gh65ghbtg56hg3g5ty7uReceived Command wedwedewd6y45g4Received Command fcvdfc vReceived ComRCE_vrff \
Rece mcmprepmoinReceivedCommanAPcdcdcdcReceived CommanP"
def checkit(val):
   resp=[]
   test_comment=[]
 if val=='0x01':
     print "reached condition"
     if re.search("Received Command fcvdfc:",res):
        resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x02'):
 #if re.search("Received",res):
    resp.append(0)
    else:
        print "reached else condition"
        resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x03'):
     if re.search("Received Command wedwedewd:",res):
        resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x04'):
     if re.search("Receive 1",res):
        resp.append(0)
     else:
        print "reached else condition"
        resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x05'):
     if re.search("Receiv2",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x06'):
     if re.search("Recei2",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x07'):
     if re.search("Received2 Co",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x08'):
     if re.search("Receiv3",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x09'):
     if re.search("Received7",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x0a'):
     print "reached condition"
     if re.search("Received8",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x0b'):
     print "reached condition"
     if re.search("Received8",res):
         resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x0c'):
      print "reached condition"
      if re.search("ReceivedT9",res):
          resp.append(0)
      else:
          print "reached else condition"
          resp.append(-1)
 elif(val=='0x0d'):
     print "reached condition"
     if re.search("fwefef",res):
        resp.append(0)
     else:
         print "reached else condition"
         resp.append(-1)
     #return
 test_comment.append(str(res))
 resp.append(test_comment)
 #print test_comment
 return resp

li=['0x01','0x02','0x03','0x04','0x05','0x06','0x07','0x08','0x09','0x0a','0x0b','0x0c','0x0d'];
for i in range(10):
   val=random.choice(li)
   print val
   ret=checkit(val);
   print "response:",ret,"\n"
```